# QtSharp | SetProperty in QML from CodeBehind

Tags: c#, qt, qml

I'm using `QtSharp` to display a `QWidget` in a seperate "`window`". Now my problem is, how to update a `property` (in my example `projector.name`) which is defined in the `qml` from code behind.

#### Code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int count = 0;
    private Projector _Projector;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += _OnLoaded;
    }

    private void _OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            var qtApp = new QApplication(ref count, null);
        }
        _Projector = new Projector();

    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClickOpen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _Projector.Show();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClickPaint(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _Projector.X += 10;
        _Projector.Y += 5;
        if(_Projector.QuickWidget.Hidden)
            _Projector.QuickWidget.Show();
        else
        {
            _Projector.QuickWidget.Hide();                
        }
        _Projector.Paint();
    }
}

public class Projector : QWidget
{
    public int X { get; set; } = 123;
    public int Y { get; set; } = 12;
    public QQuickWidget QuickWidget;

    public Projector()
    {
        WindowTitle = "Paint Demo";

        Resize(800, 800);
        Show();

        QuickWidget = new QQuickWidget(this);
        QuickWidget.Source = new QUrl(@"\QML\main.qml");
        QuickWidget.RootContext.SetContextProperty("projector", this);            
        QuickWidget.SetProperty("name", new QVariant("Hello"));
        QuickWidget.resizeMode = QQuickWidget.ResizeMode.SizeRootObjectToView;
        QuickWidget.Geometry = new QRect(50, 10, 100, 300);
        QuickWidget.UpdatesEnabled = true;
        QuickWidget.Show();
    }

    protected override void OnPaintEvent(QPaintEvent e)
    {
        base.OnPaintEvent(e);
        var painter = new QPainter(this);
        painter.SetRenderHint ( QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing );

        DrawPatternsEx ( painter );
        painter.End();
    }

    void DrawPatternsEx(QPainter ptr)
    {
        ptr.SetPen(PenStyle.SolidLine);
        ptr.SetPen(QColor.FromRgb(255,0,0));

        ptr.DrawLine(0, Y, Size.Width, Y);
        ptr.DrawLine(X, 0, X, Size.Height);
    }

    public void Paint()
    {
        QuickWidget.Update();
        Update();
    }
}
```

#### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 300
    height: 600

    Rectangle {
        id: headerSchritt
        width: 300
        height: 50
        color: "#ff8629"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0

        Text {
            y: 9
            text: qsTr("Schritt:")
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            font.bold: false
            font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
        }
    }


    Text {
        id: currentStepLabel
        anchors.top: headerSchritt.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 10
        text: qsTr("Aktuell:")
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
    }
    Text {
        id: currentStep
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
        text: projector.currentStep
        font.bold: true
        anchors.top: headerSchritt.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.margins: 10
    }

    Text {
        id: numStepsLabel
        anchors.top: currentStep.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 10
        text: qsTr("Gesamt:")
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
    }
    Text {
        id: numSteps
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
        text: projector.numSteps
        anchors.top: currentStep.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.margins: 10
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: headerComponent
        height: 50
        color: "#ff8629"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.top: numSteps.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 10

        Text {
            y: 9
            text: qsTr("Komponente:")
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: name
        text: projector.name
        wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
        font.family: "Courier"
        anchors.top: headerComponent.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 10
        font.italic: false
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
    }

    Text {
        id: componentCode
        text: projector.cCode
        wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
        anchors.top: name.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 10
        font.bold: true
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
    }

    Text {
        id: componentName
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
        text: projector.cName
        wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
        anchors.top: componentCode.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 10
    }

    Image {
        id: componentPicture
        width: height
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.top: componentName.bottom
        anchors.margins: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        source: "image://componentpictures/" + projector.cId
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }
```

}

In `Qt` I have to define a `Q_PROPERTY` which is not available in the `QtSharp` library. Maybe I'm just missing something?

Comment: How that property is defined in your QML ?

Comment: Have a look at: `text: projector.name`

Comment: So you are setting the text of that element to be the property value ?

Comment: How about declaring the property directly in qml

Comment: Same result. The initial value is taken, but the binding with code behind is not working. See my answer below from the `QtSharp` developer.

Comment: Did you try bind the qml object in c++ first

Comment: What I mean is doing everything the opposite .. changing the qml property value from c++

Comment: That would be the compromise solution. Another way would be to create everything from code behind without qml.

Comment: As you say its not supported .. so may be you are left with the compromise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually possible following the guidelines from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html.

You have to define a property in the root QML object as pointed out by Mohammad (here `componentName`) like so:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 300
    height: 600

    property string componentName: "test"

    Rectangle {
        id: headerSchritt
        width: 300
        height: 50
        color: "#ff8629"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0

        Text {
            y: 9
            text: qsTr("Schritt:")
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            font.bold: false
            font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
        }
    }


    Text {
        id: currentStepLabel
        anchors.top: headerSchritt.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 10
        text: qsTr("Aktuell:")
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
    }
    Text {
        id: currentStep
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
        text: projector.currentStep
        font.bold: true
        anchors.top: headerSchritt.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.margins: 10
    }

    Text {
        id: numStepsLabel
        anchors.top: currentStep.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 10
        text: qsTr("Gesamt:")
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
    }
    Text {
        id: numSteps
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
        text: projector.numSteps
        anchors.top: currentStep.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.margins: 10
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: headerComponent
        height: 50
        color: "#ff8629"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.top: numSteps.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 10

        Text {
            y: 9
            text: qsTr("Komponente:")
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: name
        text: root.componentName
        wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
        font.family: "Courier"
        anchors.top: headerComponent.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 10
        font.italic: false
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
    }

    Text {
        id: componentCode
        text: projector.cCode
        wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
        anchors.top: name.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 10
        font.bold: true
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
    }

    Text {
        id: componentName
        font.pixelSize: projector.fontSize
        text: projector.cName
        wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
        anchors.top: componentCode.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 10
    }

    Image {
        id: componentPicture
        width: height
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.top: componentName.bottom
        anchors.margins: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        source: "image://componentpictures/" + projector.cId
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }
}
```

Then you can access the defined property via the `RootObject` contained in the `QQuickWidget` by calling `Info.RootObject.SetProperty("componentName", "lorem ipsum");`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int count = 0;
    private Projector _Projector;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += _OnLoaded;
    }

    private void _OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            var qtApp = new QApplication(ref count, null);
        }
        _Projector = new Projector();

    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClickOpen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _Projector.Show();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClickPaint(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _Projector.X += 10;
        _Projector.Y += 5;
        if(_Projector.Info.Hidden)
            _Projector.Info.Show();
        else
        {
            _Projector.Info.Hide();                
        }
        _Projector.Paint();
    }
}

public class Projector : QWidget
{
    public int X { get; set; } = 123;
    public int Y { get; set; } = 12;

    public QQuickWidget Info;
    public QObject qmlRoot;

    public Projector()
    {
        WindowTitle = "Paint Demo";
        Palette.SetColor(QPalette.ColorRole.Background, QColor.FromRgb(0,0,0));

        Resize(800, 800);
        Show();

        Info = new QQuickWidget(this);
        Info.Source = new QUrl(@"\QML\main.qml");
        Info.RootObject.SetProperty("componentName", "lorem ipsum");
        Info.resizeMode = QQuickWidget.ResizeMode.SizeRootObjectToView;
        Info.Geometry = new QRect(50, 10, 100, 300);
        Info.Show();
    }

    protected override void OnPaintEvent(QPaintEvent e)
    {
        base.OnPaintEvent(e);
        var painter = new QPainter(this);
        painter.SetRenderHint ( QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing );

        DrawPatternsEx ( painter );
        painter.End();
    }

    void DrawPatternsEx(QPainter ptr)
    {
        ptr.SetPen(PenStyle.SolidLine);
        ptr.SetPen(QColor.FromRgb(255,0,0));

        ptr.DrawLine(0, Y, Size.Width, Y);
        ptr.DrawLine(X, 0, X, Size.Height);
    }

    public void Paint()
    {
        Update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that it's actually not supported (https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp/issues/74) yet:

> I am afraid you cannot at present. The interaction with QML is not added yet.
>
> I definitely hope it would be near but I cannot tell. Integration with QML is a must, no second opinion, but I am just afraid I have been really unable to spare any time on the bindings in the last month. I still have some work to finish for templates and I won't start with QML before that. So any help is welcome. For example, it would help me to know how to theoretically do it. I know PyQt does it by manual tinkering with the meta-object system of Qt but I have still not got to the details.